# JPA - does not work cascada type all

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, eclipselink

I have a problem with saving the list of entities in the database.

I have entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "movies")
@Data
public class MovieEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(unique = true, updatable = false)
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "movie", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<MovieDescription> descriptions;
}
```

with classes

```
@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@DiscriminatorValue(value = MovieField.Values.DESCRIPTION)
public class MovieDescription extends MovieInfo {

    private String description;
}
```

which inherits from

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "movies_info")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "dtype")
@Data
public class MovieInfo {

    @Id
    @Column(unique = true, updatable = false)
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private MovieEntity movie;
}
```

Although I am using `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` when using such a code

```
final MovieEntity movie = new MovieEntity();
    movie.setStatus(EditStatus.WAITING);
    movie.setTitle(movieDTO.getTitle());
    movie.setType(movieDTO.getType());
    movieDTO.getDescription().ifPresent(description -> {
        MovieDescription movieDescription = new MovieDescription();
        movieDescription.setDescription(description);
        movie.getDescriptions().add(movieDescription);
    });
this.movieRepository.save(movie);
```

is saved to the database the object itself `MovieEntity`without `MovieDescription`. The mapped list does not save to the database. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case `MovieDescription` class is the relation owner. This is implied by

```
@OneToMany(*mappedBy = "movie"*, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<MovieDescription> descriptions;
```

JPA persists relations only with owner sides but you are not setting a `MovieEntity` link in your description

```
    MovieDescription movieDescription = new MovieDescription();
    movieDescription.setDescription(description);
    movie.getDescriptions().add(movieDescription);
```

Add the next line for it to work:

```
    movieDescription.setMovie(movie);
```

Comment: Should I save this entity separately? Because I added movieDescription.setMovie(movie);, but still only save MovieEnity.

Comment: No. Cascade will do it for you. It is already saving just without link to `MovieEntity`.

Comment: It's strange because it does not work. https://zapodaj.net/b3022ab068426.png.html Saves MovieEntity itself.

Comment: Yes. Debugger  https://zapodaj.net/e6afaed97d4f0.png.html It does not set a description at all.

Comment: How it comes that `descriptions` field is null at `println` line?

Comment: You are creating new HashSet but YOU DON'T ASSIGN IT TO ENTITY FIELD!

Comment: If not, it will new HashSet, it during movie.getDescriptions().add(movieDescription); thrown NullPointerExcpetion because there are no desired descriptions and the list is null.

Comment: Change it to if(this.descriptions == null) { this.descriptions = new HashSet<>();} return this.descriptions;  You ENTITY doesn't have a reference to the object you have instantiated.

Comment: Almost done. Saved a film and a description, but it did https://pastebin.com/zATE540g

Comment: You have an infinite recursion in hashCode methods. With JPA best practice is not to override neither equals nor hashCode. Can you remove it?